# Get ElementRef from child component Angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm trying inject multi child component into parent component with ElementRef, but something went wrong when I tried to get child component html

My child component

```
html: string = '';
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }
ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.html = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
}
```

And I want to get that child HTML in my parent component

```
var textComponent = new TextStepComponent();
console.log(textComponent.html); << child component
```

How can I do this? or Another way?

**All things of what I want is getting HTML of a component in another component**

Please help!!

Comment: You can't create a component like that. Look up component factories.

Comment: @Harangue Thanks!

Comment: do you add child component dynamically?

Comment: update the post with your `HTML` code?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by this way:

My parent component:

```
import { TextStepComponent } from './components/text/text.component';

constructor(
  private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
  private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const componentFactory = 
   this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TextStepComponent);
  const containerRef = 
   this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.dataContainer);
  console.log(containerRef);
  const dynamicComponent = 
   containerRef.createComponent(componentFactory).instance;
  dynamicComponent.data = { content: 'xxx' };
}
```